percona-toolkit как установить в docker-compose?
Пробовал
    database-toolkit:
        container_name: database-toolkit
        image: percona/percona-toolkit:latest
        restart: "no"
        user: root
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - "8071:8071"
        networks:
            - internal

но не завелось. Хочется увидеть как это делается по нормальному
